# How to sort the List<User> of names by using DitachedCriteria in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, detachedcriteria

Here, i am posting what i need from you!

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forEntityName(DomainEntity.tbl_user.toString);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("username"));
List<User> user = dao.getEntities(criteria);
```

This code is working fine, But sorting the names first UpperCase letters then LowerCase letters. I don't want that way.

But, I want both sorting at a time. Based on the alphabetical order. Here, i am using MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for case-insensitive ordering ? Then try this :

```
Order.asc("username").ignoreCase()
```

Comment: Still same problem is raising...